# A Horse of Many Different Colors...Out in the Open Plains

Tags: creature-design, environment, alternate-earth, horses

In mapping the ecology of an alternate Earth where the family Equidae still exists but the genus *Equus* does not, it is usually difficult to find a biologically suitable mythological horse as a replacement.  So difficult, in fact, that the Book of Creatures website has only one equid, the lushu of southern China.

[image]

In an alternate Earth, this is a *wild* horse living on the steppes of central Asia.  Both sexes have this striking pattern, which would make sense in a forested environment.  But the illustration by Arlyn Reid doesn't show a horse suitable for forest living.  For one thing, it looks too big and agile to maneuver between crowds of trees, and it has one hoof on each toe, which is a specific adaptation to deal with the harder ground of plains and grasslands.

So the lushu doesn't live in forests.  Nor is it poisonous, as is the conventional explanation of bright colors.  It is not sexual dimorphism (*and please, don't bring up "sexual selection", because I've seen that explanation so often that it's become a tiring trope or cliche.*)

With these factors in mind, **how else could the bright colors and bold patterns of the lushu be explained?**

Comment: It may be a tiring trope or cliche, but it is Nature’s go-to plan. David Attenborough has to discuss it a lot. :-)

Comment: *"The Book of Creatures website has only one equid":* Celtic goddess [Epona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epona); [Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus); [Bucephalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucephalus); [Morvarc'h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morvarc%27h) of Brittany; Odin's [Sleipnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleipnir). Plus [Balaam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balaam)'s speaking ass, the many [water horses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_horse), the unicorns of western European Middle Ages, and the embers-fed speaking stallions of Romanian (etc.) fairy tales.

Comment: And anyway, stripes are a [primitive marking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_markings) in equids.

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem with the coloration, have you seen zebra, okapi, giraffe, ect?

Comment: There are real-world horses that approximate that pattern.  Search for "brindle horse".  And remember that colors don't matter all that much, because mammals other than primates are dichromats.

Comment: @AlexP  Have you even visited A Book of Creatures?

Comment: @jamesqf  Which is why I had to emphasize on the "wild" part of it, because brindle horses are just one color variation of the domesticated horse.

Comment: @John  Zebra stripes are just for defense against biting flies.

Comment: @JohnWDailey: We don't actually know that, because (other than Przewalski's horse: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Przewalski%27s_horse ) there aren't any actual wild horses, just the descendants of escaped or abandoned domestic horses.  (Which can fairly easily be returned to domestication.  I've been riding one for years.)  AFAIK nobody knows when the gene(s) for BR1 brindle apeared, so there's no real reason they couldn't have appeared early on (and the color pattern been strengthened) in an alternate history.

Comment: @JohnWDailey I would like a source for that.

Comment: @John  https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2019/02/zebra-stripes-confuse-biting-flies-causing-them-abort-their-landings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four possibilities I can think of:

1. Make these plains extremely colorful, so that the lushus blend in properly. That could be a seasonal thing, if (say) the predators of these lushus migrate, and only appear in the lushus' territory during the colorful season.
2. Make it the defensive strategy that some birds use, such that predators will tend to pursue the more colorful specimens, which would be adults who speed away from their plain-colored offspring when a predator approaches.
3. Make the primary predator colorblind, so that the bright colors (which allow lushus to see each other across long distances) are a camouflage of grey and black lines to a predator.
4. Introduce another species (possibly extinct) that was brightly colored and extremely dangerous. The lushus would have evolve to mimic that coloration, counting on the threat-level of the other species to ward off predators.

It's worth noting that 'brightness' isn't necessarily the key factor here; the ability of the predator to distinguish patterns is more important. Thus you get effects like butterfly wings that give a pattern like the eyes of a larger animal, or brightly colored fish who swim in schools that create streaks and patterns of color as a group which confuses the vision of predators. If brightly colored streaks make it hard for a predator to figure out exactly what it's looking at, that would be an evolutionary advantage for the lushu.

Answer (score 3):

The Lushu roams in a large heard and is predated on by a large tiger like species of animal. When a predator is seen, the Lushu stampede as a large group or several large groups. Their stripes provide a sort of dazzle camouflage a bit like that used by Zebras.

With all the animals running about in all directions it would be difficult during the approach for the predator to pick out one particular prey Lushu, how fast it was moving or even which way it was moving.

Comment: The thing with the zebra is that it's now believed that the stripes are an invisibility cloak against biting flies.

Answer (score -1):

Are the markings necessarily stable? You could be looking at a creature that shifts its color and pattern as radically as an octopus does. Octopus does it both for camouflage and for language signaling to other octopi. Depending upon how intelligent you want these creatures to be, the bright colors would show well far across the plains, telling other lushu “Black means food here” or “I see danger... run toward my blue flank and away from my red flank.” And, yes, some ripple patterns could mean, “I’m in heat, come catch me if you can.”

Comment: For that to work, you'd need an entirely different kind of hair on this horse. Octopi change colors because of chromatophores in their skin; a horse's coloration comes from the colors of hair, which is a stable protein.